# How to retrieve a mongo document with an array of objects that have matching attribute

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection of user documents, each with an embedded array of clients. Each object in the array has a clientID.

I wanted to retrieve the user document with a client, in the clients array, that has a clientID matching a passed clientID.

But all the examples I have come across just retrieve the object instead of returning the document. I wanted to do this using the mgo library

```
var results []model.Clients   
err := db.C("users").Find(nil).Select(bson.M{"clients": bson.M{"$elemMatch":q }}).All(&results)
```

The above returns just a clients array. But I wanted a users array.

```
[
    {
        "userID": "1",
        clients: [
            {
                "clientID": "12",
                "data": {},
                "customers": [
                    "customerID": "0123",
                    "data": {

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "clientID": "123",
                "data": {},
                "customers": [
                    "customerID": "0123",
                    "data": {

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "userID": "2",
        clients: [
            {
                "clientID": "12",
                "data": {},
                "customers": [
                    "customerID": "0123",
                    "data": {

                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "clientID": "13",
                "data": {},
                "customers": [
                    "customerID": "0123",
                    "data": {

                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Query.Select()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Query.Select) enables selecting which fields should be retrieved for the results, not for specifying filter criteria. Filter criterial should be passed to [`Collection.Find()`](https://godoc.org/github.com/globalsign/mgo#Collection.Find).

```
var results []model.User   
err := db.C("users").Find(bson.M{"clients": bson.M{"$elemMatch":q}}).All(&results)
```

You may also use `"clients.clientID"` to designate the `clientID` in the `clients` array:

```
var results []model.User   
err := db.C("users").Find(bson.M{"clients.clientID": "12"}).All(&results)
```

Comment: sorry, i wanted to get the user document, not the clients. my code is not correct. i wanted an alternative to that.

Comment: @pro Sorry, copy-paste mistake. My answer shows how to get user documents (not clients).